# Strip all br tags from the start of HTML text until next element is text node Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

**Lets say I have this code:**

```
<div class ="element">
  <br>
  <span>
    <br>
      <span>
       <br>
        text node
        <br>
      </span>
     <br>
  </span>
</div>

<div class ="element">
  <br>
  <span>
    <br>
    <br>
        text node
  </span>
</div>
```

**I want to loop each element had class "element" and remove all `br` tags until loop reach text node then stop removing `br` and code looks like this:**

```
<div class ="element">
  <span>
      <span>
        text node
        <br>
      </span>
      <br>
  </span>
</div>

<div class ="element">
  <span>
        text node
  </span>
</div>
```

**update**

```js
var stop2 = false;
var walk_the_DOM2 = function walk2(node, func) {
//func(node);
node = node.firstChild;


while (node && !stop2) {      
walk2(node, func); 

if(func(node)== true){
stop2 = true;
}
 
  node = node.nextSibling;  
 
}
};




$('.element').each(function(index, elem) {
var hh  = elem;
 
stop2 = false;
walk_the_DOM2(hh, function(el) {

if(el.tagName =="BR"){
alert(el.tagName);
$(el).css('display', 'none'); 
}else if(el.tagName == undefined){

if($(el).text().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').replace(/(\r\n\t|\n|\r\t)/gm,"").length > 0){
alert($(el).text());
return true;
}
} 
}); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class ="element">
  <br>
  <span>
    <br>
      <span>
       <br>
        text node
        <br>

      </span>
     <br>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks like a nice code request.

Comment: why vote down !!!

Comment: listen i did tried so many codes but i didn't post it ok

Comment: i just need some hints of how to do it

Comment: Here is another text explaining [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Node

---

Since there is a need to reference elements and text within the DOM, we'll use the [Node interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node). When using the Node interface, it's important to keep in mind that a node is an element, text, comments, a document, or even whitespace. Whitespace is what makes traversing the DOM by referencing nodes so difficult. The Demo below shows us a way to use NodeLists, filter out the desired elements by conditions, and deal with textNodes and whitespace properly.

The following is a list of properties and methods used in the Demo:

[**querySelectorAll()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

[**parentNode**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode)

[**nextSibling**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling)

[**nodeType**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType)

[**removeChild**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild)

[**textContent**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

[**test()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

---

### Demo

**Details commented in Demo**

---

```js
// Collect all .elements in a NodeList
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.element');

/* for each .element...
|| Collect all of .element's <br>
*/
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  var brs = elements[i].querySelectorAll('br');

  // for each <br> in the current .element...
  for (let j = 0; j < brs.length; j++) {

    // Find current <br>'s parent
    var parent = brs[j].parentNode;

    // Check what type of node is next after current <br>
    var textCheck = brs[j].nextSibling.nodeType;

    // if the next node is NOT a nodeType TEXT (3)... 
    if (textCheck !== 3) {

      //... Remove the current <br>...
      parent.removeChild(brs[j]);
    } else {

      /* ...but if the next node is a textNode,
      || use wsCheck function to see if it is only whitespace...
      */
      if (wsCheck(brs[j].nextSibling)) {

        //...if it is only whitespace then remove current <br>... 
        parent.removeChild(brs[j]);

        /*...otherwise if it is a textNode with text
        || remove current <br>
        || break out of the inner for loop and continue to the
        || outer for loop
        */
      } else {
        parent.removeChild(brs[j]);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

function wsCheck(node) {
  return !(/[^\t\n\r ]/.test(node.textContent));
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <br>
  <span>
    <br>
      <span>
       <br>
        text node one
        <br>
      </span>
  <br>
  </span>
</div>

<div class="element">
  <br>
  <span>
    <br>
    <br>
        text node two
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you this is exactly what i want ..i will edit my post later to see how i did it too but its not good as you code ...

Comment: plz check my update  the code is working well in my PC but removing br not working at all i changed the br tag css display to none instead thanks..

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Removing the <br> is a little tricky because the plain JavaScript method `removeChild()` depends on you knowing the target's parent. Using jQuery [`remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) method is a lot easier because you can directly select the target to remove.

Answer (score 1):

write your code like this :

```
<div class ="element">
<br>
<span>
<br>
  <span>
   <br>
    <span class="anchor">text node</span>
    <br>
  </span>
 <br>
 </span>
 </div>
<div class ="element">
<br>
<span>
   <br>
   <br>
    <span class="anchor">text node</span>
</span>
</div>
```

now use this loop to remove all previous `br`:

```
$('.element').each(function () {
        var anchor = $(this).find('span:contains(text node)');
        anchor.prev("br").remove();
    });
```

you can use anchor class instead it's text but using anchor span just for text is necessary,means if you write `<br>` in anchor `<span>` it will not remove.you can remove anchor class in this code , i don't use it.

Comment: unfortunately  i have no control of the content of the HTML page i need generic way to detect br tag before text node thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok.you have another option; in loop get `html()` of your `.element`. convert it to string then find index of `text node`. now replaceAll `<br>` with `''`. At end replace `.element.html()` with new string you made.

Comment: but  text node content maybe different on each page and on each element what i need is  to loop on each element had class "element" and then check every child element if have no text node at first level of that child  then remove br tag if exist then go deeper until loop find text node in last child then remove the last br in that child then stop loop but i don't know how manage by code

Comment: Ok.get html of element in string then save in 2 variable.for first var remove all tags ( use regex or write it manualy).
Now you have text node that can use it for searching.do not forgot remove white spaces in var1.if you want go deeper using loop you can save tags in a array or object then search for text node and use index to remove array elements that have <br>